# Error in converting torch tensor to numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

```
var1 = tensor([[[[0., 1., 1.,  ..., 1., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 1.,  ..., 0., 0., 0.],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 0., 0., 1.],
          ...,
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.],
          [0., 0., 0.,  ..., 1., 1., 1.]]]])

print(var1.size())
print(type(var1))
print(var1.dtype)
```

Output:

```
torch.Size([1, 1, 480, 640])
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
torch.float32
```

**When I tried to convert torch tensor into numpy.ndarray, all values became zero.**

```
nump_var1 = var1.argmax(dim=1).squeeze(0).cpu().numpy()
print(nump_var1)
print(nump_var1.shape)
print(type(nump_var1))
print(nump_var1.dtype)
```

Output:

```
    [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
     ...
     [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
     [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

(480, 640)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
int64
```

Can anyone point out the mistake I have made?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what is `argmax` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Thanks your question resolved my question :D

Answer (score 0):

As [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) hinted at in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74669588/error-in-converting-torch-tensor-to-numpy-ndarray#comment131794884_74669588), `var1.argmax(dim=1)` will result in a zero tensor because you have `var1.size(1) == 1`.